# How to fetch data from Hbase table which is running on linux system and java progamme which is run on window Could not locate executable null\bin\

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How to fetch data from Hbase table which is running on linux system and java progamme which is run on window Could not locate executable null\bin\

//
this is my code to connect

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.20.129");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.20.129:60010");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method , call before connecting.

```
private static void workaround() {
        //workaround for = java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
        File workaround = new File(".");
        System.getProperties().put("hadoop.home.dir", workaround.getAbsolutePath());
        new File("./bin").mkdirs();
        try {
            new File("./bin/winutils.exe").createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you write the whole code to get the data from linux hbase table to window java class

Comment: that is your answer to your problem. I can not write that code for you, that you can easily find on internet.